# Gravity Forms User Registration

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have followed the directions on https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/user-registration-add-on/ and I'm trying to create a custom user registration form.

I have a more complicated form I'd like to get working that includes several custom meta fields, however, in an effort to get things working I've simplified the form to just a "Name" field, "Email", and "Username".

The form:

[image: The form]

The settings in Forms -> User Registrations:

[image: The settings in Forms -> User Registrations]

The settings in Forms -> Settings -> User Registrations

[image: The settings in Forms -> Settings -> User Registrations]

The contents of the Test Contact page:

[image: The contents of the Test Contact page]

I've confirmed that user registration is enabled, yet whenever I submit the form, I get the email and I see it listed as an "entry", however the user is not created.

Comment: What happens if you activate the user? (If you can do so).

Comment: There's no user to activate.  The form submits successfully, however there's no user added to the user list.

Comment: Oh!  I completely missed that.  I see what you're saying.  I didn't notice the "active user" button.

That was pretty bone headed of me.  I'd love to accept that as an answer of some sorts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With "Enable user activation" + "manually" options, you will need to activate each user in the WordPress Admin Dashboard.

Found [here](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/setup-the-user-registration-add-on/)